# How to generate an API url to get data from Wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress.com

Currently, I want to get data from my personal blog on WordPress to put through my personal website. I tried using this URL: **https://shopssam.wordpress.com/wp/v2/posts** and it didn't work. After a while of researching, there must be more tweaks in **PermaLinks**. And I can't find it anywhere in the WordPress home page settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wordpress.com use **different REST API** than normal wordpress.org.

First find your Site ID from link bellow:
https://dashboard.wordpress.com/wp-admin/index.php?page=my-blogs

Then replace SITEID in below parameter to get all posts:
[https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/{YOUR_SITE_ID_GOES_HERE}/posts](https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/%7BYOUR_SITE_ID_GOES_HERE%7D/posts)

Comment: I've done it already. Thank you very much. At first I thought siteID was a number. Turns out that was the path name of my blog

Answer (score 1):

For those who need a clearer answer. You can read the information here: **https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/**. This is a document for Wordpress.com, be careful when using Wordpress, because despite having the same name, **WordPress.com** and **WordPress.org** have completely different ways of working. And here is the exact API URL that I modified to get the data: **https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/shopssam.wordpress.com/posts**

Which **shopssam.wordpress.com** is my blog URL.